# Mobicents / jdiameter deployment on cloud environment

Tags: cloud, diameter-protocol, mobicents

Dealing with an issue on mobicents/jdiameter and have a question.  Glad if anyone could answer it.

What I want to do is to deploy a diameter-server application on a cloud environment. Due to the nature of the cloud, each time a deployment is done, a new IP is assigned to the container that diameter application is running.

However, there is a localPeer setting on jdiameter which the IP of the running server needs to be configured. Since IP changes on each deployment, I can not configure an IP address to the setting below. (Tried 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0 and no IPAddress) Because of this, although diameter stack gets initialized, the application refuses any connection attempt from external servers.  How can I overcome this ? I'm using restcomm-diameter.jdiameter version 1.7.1-123.

The setting I mentioned is like below:

```
<LocalPeer>
                <URI value="aaa://x.y.z.t:3868" />
                <IPAddresses>
                        <IPAddress value="x.y.z.t" />
                </IPAddresses>
```